# Is there a way of adding to a table based on a condition?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

I've been trying to work on this issue with my oracle 11g home project database for several days. Can't seem to wrap my head around the issue. Maybe I'm missing something glaringly obvious.

I am trying to add a row into a table based off multiple conditions on the data already within that table. Such as adding the time schedule of 1pm to 2pm as long as the time slot is not already taken over or overlapping another time slot. Oracle doesn't have a boolean function that I can use to check against if a table already contains such information. Should I create another temporary table and try to left or right join both tables if the time slot is available?

```
INSERT INTO Room(Building_Name, RoomNum, CourseNum, StaffID, Season, Year, 
Course_Days, Start_Time, End_Time)  
VALUES (buildingName, roomNum, courseNum, staffID, season, year, courseDays, 
startTime, endTime)  
Where EXISTS (Select * 
  From Room
      Where (StaffID = 12312 AND Start_Time < 14:00 AND End_Time < 14:00);
```

Thank you

Comment: Isn't `EXISTS()` a boolean function that checks if a table contains information? If you edit your question to add your table structure, some example data, and a query, we could probably be more helpful.

Comment: Okay, just added it.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of VALUES use SELECT...FROM DUAL:

```
INSERT INTO Room(Building_Name, RoomNum, CourseNum, StaffID, Season, Year, Course_Days, Start_Time, End_Time)  
SELECT buildingName, roomNum, courseNum, staffID, season, year, courseDays, startTime, endTime
FROM DUAL
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM Room
  WHERE StaffID = 12312 AND Start_Time < '14:00' AND End_Time < '14:00'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I see what you're asking. I'm not clear where those values are coming from (buildingName, etc) - is it part of a PL/SQL block? But I'd rewrite it something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Room (Building_Name, RoomNum, CourseNum, StaffID, Season, Year, 
    Course_Days, Start_Time, End_Time)  
SELECT (buildingName, roomNum, courseNum, staffID, season, year, courseDays, 
    startTime, endTime)  
From dual
Where NOT EXISTS (Select * 
      From Room
      Where (StaffID = 12312 AND Start_Time < 14:00 AND End_Time < 14:00);
```

I do this pretty often with manual inserts, where I'm specifying all the values, but I want to make sure that they don't already exist in the table. In that case, it might look more like:

```
INSERT INTO Room (Building_Name, RoomNum, CourseNum, StaffID, Season, Year, 
    Course_Days, Start_Time, End_Time)  
SELECT 'Building1', 117, 9782, 12312 as sid, 'Spring', 2020, 'MWF', 
    '1300' as startTime, '1400' as endTime 
From dual d
Where NOT EXISTS (Select * 
      From Room
      Where (StaffID = d.sid AND (d.startTime between Start_Time and End_Time-1
                                  OR d.endTime between Start_Time+1 and End_Time));
```

Comment: Ah! I think this is exactly what I need. I didn't know dual can be used as a table with more than one column and table! Thank you.

Comment: Ah! I think this is exactly what I need. I didn't know dual can be used as a table with more than one column and table! Thank you.

Comment: I dont think that this will work. paranthesis for select columns must be removed.